# how to write a spark scala schema for complex datatypes like map,struct,array

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, complex-data-types

Please find the data format

```
c3f36c25-2546-48b2-bd72-1b5e5dcae2ab/1620247529/{6032:{"advertisers":{"Amoma":[{"eurocents":17256,"breakfast":false}]
```

tried the below

```
valsschema=List(
                ("Userid", StringType, true),
                ("unix_time", IntegerType, true),
("hotelresults",MapType(IntegerType,true,StructType(("advertisers",MapType(StringType,true,ArrayType(StructType("eurocents",IntegerType,true,"breakfast",BooleanType,true))))))
              )
```

Comment: can you please post your question with more clearer info with exception/error you are facing

Comment: I need to create a hive table via sparkscala  for the above  mentioned data          
 . Need to create a schema . i am getting the error as                                                                                                                                        not enough arguments for method apply: (name: String, dataType: org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType, nullable: Boolean, metadata: org.apache.spark.sql.types.Metadata)org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField in object StructField. Unspecified value parameter dataType

Comment: is there any other way to create schema for my data

Comment: you JSON in the question is invalid . Please correct it first

Comment: c3f36c25-2546-48b2-bd72-1b5e5dcae2ab\u00011620247529\u00016032\u0003Amoma\u000617256\bfalse  => This is the original data and this is not JSON . i have converted it

Comment: can you add two more lines of your input data ??

Comment: c3f36c25-2546-48b2-bd72-1b5e5dcae2ab\u00011620247529\u00016032\u0003Amoma\u000617256\bfalse\u0005Tui.com\u000617149\bfalse\u000739448\bfalse\u00028001\u0003expedia\u000634650\bfalse\u0005Mercure\u000621490\bfalse\u0005Destinia\u000613719\bfalse\u000723011\bfalse\u00079788\bfalse\u0005Tui.com\u000625723\bfalse\u0005booking.com\u000629272\bfalse\u000728400\bfalse

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to make a StructType using the [add](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/StructType.html#add-java.lang.String-org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType-) method.

It seems like your overall file is a CSV format with "/" (slash) delimiter:

```scala
// create initial DataFrame with JSON data inside of 3rd column
val df:DataFrame = spark.read.format("csv").option("delimiter", "/").option("header", "false").option("inferSchema", "false").load("62132524.txt").toDF("UserId", "UnixTime", "HotelResults")
```

Your 3rd column JSON was invalid so it is changed here:

```
c3f36c25-2546-48b2-bd72-1b5e5dcae2ab/1620247529/{"advertisers":{"Amoma":[{"eurocents":17256,"breakfast":false}]}}
```

Create a schema to parse the JSON using the `from_json` method (uses wildcard imports to make sure everything is imported):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

// prepare StructType with inner StructType
val detailType:StructType = new StructType().add("eurocents", IntegerType).add("breakfast", BooleanType)
val jsonSchema:StructType = new StructType().add("advertisers", MapType(StringType, ArrayType(detailType, false)))

// Now, the JSON Schema can be used:
df.select(from_json(col("HotelResults"), jsonSchema) as "HotelResults2").select(col("HotelResults2.*")).show
```

**Edited based on comments (parse flat file directly)**

The built-in CSV parser can only parse a file with one delimiter. A workaround is to use the [split](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.2/scala/collection/immutable/StringOps.html#split(separators:Array[Char]):Array[String]) Scala String method.

```scala
// Read data into a flat RDD
val rawDF = spark.sparkContext.textFile("rawdata.dat")

// Create case class (I added 3 fields, but you will need to add the rest)
case class Record(id: Int, advertiser: String, euroCents: Int)

// Create function converting an array of values to the case class
def arrToRecord(a:Array[String]): Record = Record(a(0).toInt, a(1), a(2).toInt)

// Use one of the approaches below - they should be equivalent in your case
val mappedDF:DataFrame = rawDF.map((s:String) => arrToRecord(s.split("[\u0006\u0003\u0005\u0007\u0008\u0002]"))).toDF()
// OR
val mappedDF:DataFrame = rawDF.map((s:String) => arrToRecord(s.split(Array('\u0006','\u0003','\u0005','\u0007','\u0008','\u0002')))).toDF()
```

Result

```
mappedArr.show
+----+----------+---------+
|  id|advertiser|euroCents|
+----+----------+---------+
|6032|     Amoma|    17256|
+----+----------+---------+
```

Comment: My data format is of .dat file .Please find the original data and please let me know how to read it as a csv file. i Used spark.read.format("csv").option("delimiter", "/u001").option("header", "false").option("inferSchema", "false").load(filepath/.dat) and i got the first two cols as col0/col1/col2.. but col2 has unicode characters and cant befiltered using delimter as there are colection items . Hope it is clear now. @ELinda.. We are almost near to the solution .

Comment: {"_c0":"c3f36c25-2546-48b2-bd72-1b5e5dcae2ab","_c1":"1620247529","_c2":"6032\u0003Amoma\u000617256\bfalse\u0005Tui.com\u000617149\bfalse\u000739448\bfalse\u00028001\u0003expedia\u000634650\bfalse\u0005Mercure\u000621490\bfalse\u0005Destinia\u000613719\bfalse\u000723011\bfalse\u00079788\bfalse\u0005Tui.com\u000625723\bfalse\u0005booking.com\u000629272\bfalse\u000728400\bfalse\u00026033\u0003Amoma\u00065361\bfalse}

Comment: see section "Edit" above

Comment: I have created a dataframe successfully now i need the schema. i have created one but i am getting the error i have mentioned the data as well as the schema created below  val sschema = new StructType()
      .add("userid",StringType)
      .add("unix_time",StringType)
   .add("advertisers", MapType(StringType,ArrayType(new StructType().add("eurocents", IntegerType).add("breakfast", BooleanType))))
    val rawDF = spark.sparkContext.textFile("C:/Users/Rajaraman/Desktop/task/data/hive.dat")

Comment: i rephrased the code as 
val df1 = rawDF.map((s:String) => (s.split("['\u0001','\u0002','\u0003','\u0004',\u0005','\u0006','\u0007','\u0008',\u0009,\u0010]"))).toDF()
and got the below ouput 
|[c3f36c25-2546-48b2-bd72-1b5e5dcae2ab, 1620247529, 6032, Amoma, 17256, false
c0a0b114-d1f9-491b-b6c3-ec90d05881ac, 1620208508, 9089, Tui.com, 23418, false  @Elinda-Please review

Comment: yes that looks like it could be right. I am not as familiar with your data, you would need to know what those fields mean :)

Comment: [c3f36c25-2546-48b2-bd72-1b5e5dcae2ab, 1620247529, 6032, Amoma, 17256, false, Tui.com, 17149, false] ----- the third column is the map element which has the thwo array elements . Need schema for this . 
- this is not working

Comment: val detail = new StructType().add("eurocents", IntegerType).add("breakfast", BooleanType)
val sschema = new StructType()
      .add("userid",StringType)
      .add("unix_time",StringType)
   .add("advertisers", MapType(StringType,ArrayType(detail, false))) -problem in the last line @ ELinda